# .cvs to .ctt convert

Tags: delphi, contacts, msn

Goodday all,

I want to know how i can write a .ctt file from a .cvs file? it has to do with the msn contact list. hotmail works with .cvs msn works with  .ctt

is this possible in any way?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's considered good form to try first, and show what you tried. Did you open these files in Notepad, for example, and look at their format, and then try to write something that would convert from the one to the other? They are both simple text formats, you should be able to at least try something first, otherwise it sounds like you are asking "can someone write my whole program for me".

Comment: What sense does it make to convert a Canvas image file into a Messenger contact list?

Answer (score 1):

The .CTT file is just a text file in XML format. Outlook can output in several formats including .CSV format (not CVS).

You can load a CSV file up using TJvCsvDataSet (a component in the Delphi Jedi VCL library), and write it out in XML with a .CTT file extension, using  OmniXML or with MSXML in Delphi.